# ClassCastException when binding to local service from another Activity

Tags: android, service, local, classcastexception

In my application I have two separated APKs. The Activity (A1) from the first APK starts local service and is able to call methods provided by this Service. Later the activity A1 starts another activity (A2) from the second APK. The A2 activity tries to connect to the local service started by A1. Both activities are running in the same process with the same SharedUserID. Service interface is provided as shown in API examples of LocalService. onBind method of service returns LocalBinder instance which has method getService().
When onServiceConnected of A2 is called I got ClassCastException when I try to cast from IBinder to MyService.LocalBinder.

In the debugger I can see that the service argument of onServiceConnected of A2 activity is the right instance of MyService.LocalBinder. I can even watch all attributes of MyService in debugger, but when I tries to cast the IBinder service to the MyService.LocalBinder I got the ClassCastException exception? Is there some way around or do I have to use AIDL?

```
public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service)
{

  try
  {
       MyService.LocalBinder binder = (MyService.LocalBinder)service;
       m_IService = binder.getService();
  }
  catch(ClassCastException e)
  {

  }


 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about this, but I'm guessing that you have compiled MyService.LocalBinder into both A1 and A2 apks. That would produce this kind of exception, because while they have the same name and the same code, they're still two separate class files. I think you would need to move the class into a shared library to make this work.

---

**Update** (responding to comment): I don't see how using an interface would be any different; as with the class, the interface would be instantiated differently on the client and server, and so result in a cast exception. You might be able to use [reflection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html) to work around this, but I don't recommend that approach -- it may not be supported by either AndroidOS or the DalvikVM.

I think the best course is to try creating the AIDL interface and see if it does the job. It could be 10x easier than trying to do something that Android seems deliberately designed to prevent.

But if you want to keep pursuing your current approach, one **possible** path would be to use the [ClassLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ClassLoader.html) to load the client class into the server. I'm not sure if this can be made to work either.

Comment: I have MyService class in Library Project so it is compiled in both APKs this what you mean? Or is there another way how to share MyService cross more applications?

Comment: @esmeralda2: If you're sure that `service` is an instance of `MyService.LocalBinder` when the exception is thrown at that cast, then I don't know of another possible cause other than a duplicate definition of `MyService.LocalBinder`. Are you sure it isn't defined in more than one location, or in more than one jar file? As a test, try instantiating a fake LocalBinder just before the cast: `MyService.LocalBinder fake = new MyService.LocalBinder();` and then see if they have the same Class: `if (fake.getClass() != service.getClass() {/* report an error */}`

Comment: Hi Dan, you were right that is the problem. When I put MyService implementation to the Library project and if APK1 and APK2 uses this lib. project then MyService implementation is in both APKs. Then indeed service.getClass() != MyService.LocalBinder.getClass(). Is there any way around? I'm not expert in java I rather work in C so is there somethig as shared libs? In java this is JAR files right? Is it possible to move MyService to JAR file if I developing for android? Or can I move the MyService to APK1 and in APK2 cast service to some interface which will be in the Library project?

Comment: @esmeralda2: It seems that library projects are specifically for sharing source code; the objects are copied from the library into the apks. (I wasn't fully aware of this until now.) I thought that I'd seen a method for sharing components between apk files, without duplicating them, but I can't find it now. It's probably easiest at this point to use AIDL.

Comment: I would like to avoid AIDL. Firstly I would have to implement Parcel for PDUs I want to pass to / from service and secondly I'm afraid of performance penalty. If you find way how to share object between APKs please let me know. What do you think about approach where I would cast service argument to interface which will provide getService method instead of casting it to LocalBinder class with getService() method?

Comment: I thought that interface will behave similar to the .h file in C. How would classLoader could help me here? I tried this but still don't know how to cast service to some interface that I would be able to use. ClassLoader cl = service.getClass().getClassLoader(); Class<?> c = cl.loadClass("localservice.MyService"); But then what can I do with the c object how to cast it to MyService from my APK? Looks like AIDL is the only way around here :(

Comment: @esmeralda2: Nothing in Java is really like a .h file in C. I don't really know, either, whether `ClassLoader` could be helpful; I just think that if there's any option other than AIDL, it would have to involve `ClassLoader`. I urge you to try AIDL, rather than assuming it wouldn't work for you.