# bindService from other app but same userid/process

Tags: android, android-service, ipc, android-binder

This is about memory-based IPC (like to [LocalService](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/bound-services.html#Binder) example) but for two apps running in the same process:

I have two apps (`App1`, `App2`) and a shared project (`Shared`) which defines some interfaces and abstract classes for both apps:

```
Shared (regular Java project, references android.jar)
    - abstract myAbstractService
    - Binder myBinder
App1 (Android Project, references Shared)
    - MainActivity
App2 (Android Project, references Shared)
    - myService extends myAbstractService
```

Both apps run within the same process (`my.process`, defined in `<application>`), 
`App2` publishes `com.www.app2.myService`:

```
<-- Both Apps run in the same process -->
<manifest <!-- *snip* --> android:sharedUserId="my.shareduser">
    <!--  ... -->
    <application <!-- *snip* --> android:process="my.process">
        <-- App2 exports the service -->
        <service android:name="com.www.app2.myService" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.www.app2.myService" />
            </intent-filter>
       </service>
```

This is the abstract `myAbstractService` (`myService` doesn't add anything new yet):

```
abstract public class GameClient extends Service
{   
    private static final String LOGTAG = "GameClient";

    private myBinder binder = new myBinder();

    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
        Log.d(LOGTAG, "onBind()");

        return this.binder;
    }

    public class myBinder extends Binder
    {
        public void sendMessage()
        {
            Log.d(LOGTAG, "sendMessage()");
        }
    }
 }
```

When I try to bind to `myService` (App2) from my `MainActivity` (App1):

```
public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) 
{
    Log.d("MS", service.getClass().toString());
    main.this.t = (myBinder) service; // Exception in this line of course
}
```

I get an exception:

> DEBUG/MS(5464): class com.www.shared.myBinder
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5464): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.www.shared.myBinder

As both apps run in the same process, memory-coupled communication should work (at least I thought). I really don't want to use the message-based or broadcast-based communication as I'll send quite some messages around.
I suspect this exception happens due two different classloaders being used for the same class? Is this approach simply not possible/wrong or am I missing something?

**Update:**
My aim is to write a very modular application, where App1 is used as a delegating and starting application of other modules (apps). As I don't want to ship `App1` with every app depending on it, I made it it's own app.

Let's say I have a third app (App3, Android project). App2 & App3 are both started by App1 (responsible for setting up connections while App2 & App3 provide different application logic (but having the same interface).

On a second thought I think this could be solved with an android library as well (App1 & Shared merged as the library with `App2` and `App3` starting an Activity of this library and waiting for the result)? However the data is not parcelable (network connections) and I have no idea how this library could be distributed independently over the android market (like `App2` and `App3` are published there but ask for the library to be installed too). Would this resolve that problem at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, you receive this exception because there are two class loaders involved.

I've added next two lines of code:

```
@Override
public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service)
{
    ...
    Log.e(TAG, "Expected class loader: "+myBinder.class.getClass().getClassLoader());
    Log.e(TAG, "Class loader: "+service.getClass().getClassLoader());
    ...
}
```

And received these logs:

```
Expected class loader: java.lang.BootClassLoader@4001bdb0
Class loader: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.inazaruk.shared.service-2.apk]
```

---

From logs its clear that another class loader was used. This actually makes sense, as you could've installed `App1` application one week later with different version of `myBinder` class (or any other class that is passed via `myBinder` interface directly or indirectly).

---

---

**Updated**:
You should stick with Android Libraries in your scenario. Note that Android Libraries are directly embedded in the application that references them. They are not distributed separately. [Here is my post](http://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/05/22/android-application-android-libraries-and-jar-libraries/) explaining how Android Libraries are different from simple jars, and other relevant nuances.

You still have a high degree of modularity in Android Library, as final Android Application only includes modules it uses. But this is compile-time modularity, not runtime modularity.

There are some issues with Android Libraries though:

1. You need to copy all components' declarations in library's `AndroidManifest.xml` into Android Application's `AndroidManifest.xml`.
2. Currently libraries do not support custom xml attributes (see my posts [here](http://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/05/22/the-case-of-android-libraries-and-custom-xml-attributes-part-2/) and [here](http://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/05/22/the-case-of-android-libraries-and-custom-xml-attributes-part-2/)).
3. Currently libraries do not support assets (see my post [here](http://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/06/26/enabling-assets-in-android-libraries/)).

The #1 is planned to be fixed soon (according to [Build Support roadmap](http://tools.android.com/roadmap) ). The #2 and #3 might get fixed in next release of SDK platform tools.

Comment: Thanks for you clarification. I have added further details for a maybe-workaround. Another idea would be to load the class at runtime from the other package (DexClassLoader). But I guess this wouldn't work either.

Comment: Thanks :) This would imply that I can not use the former App1 as an starting app anymore I guess (beside App2 starting App1, which could start App3 instead (starting App1 again to return to App3 when it's done) and that my former App1 would be deployed with every App (or module, potentially resulting in two different versions of it)?

Comment: You will not have App1, App2 and App3 anymore. You'd have Lib1 and Lib2 and will create AppX that uses Lib1 and Lib2. As a result you'll ship application that is virtually (Lib1+Lib2+AppX). And if your decide to create AppY that uses Lib2, you'd get application that is virtually (Lib2+AppY). Hope I understood your question correctly.

Comment: Ah. I want it the other way round: like App1 is the must-have component and App2/App3 are optional (and installable later on) extensions of App1. In my case, App1 initializes some network connections and hands them to a user-chosen (depending on the apps installed) app (like App2,App3). App2,3 do fancy (but different) things with these connections. But it's up to the user which functionality he wants (decided by installing the corresponding app). Thus, at compile-time I don't know which are available at the end-system.

Comment: So you basically need dynamic-time modularity (something like plug-ins). Android currently does not support this, other then remotely bound services, content providers, activities and broadcasts. In other words you need to serialize and deserialize data that you want to exchange between components from different packages (applications).

Comment: Ok thank you for your help :) Will stick with the messenger then :/ (As reflection/invoke only works with serializable data too)

Answer (score 2):

Tried this myself a while back: similar questions were previously asked at [ClassCastException when binding to local service from another Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526938/classcastexception-when-binding-to-local-service-from-another-activity) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162538/2-apks-running-in-1-process-sharing-code-and-data. The end result is pretty much the same: sharing process is NOT the same as sharing code because of the nature of the class loader hierarchy (similar to how J2EE class loaders are split).

The classes are coming from different DEX files so technically speaking the classes are different, even if the interfaces are the same. I don't believe what you want to do is possible: I see AIDL in your future.

Comment: A longer writeup (from way back in the day) is at http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2009/06/controlling-application-separation.html and basically captures the same argument.

Comment: Thanks for your literature :) Already knew the link in your comment (gave me the hint to use a sharedProcess). See my comment @inazaruk answer for a possible "work-around?" :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a class called "myBinder" in the namespace "com.www.shared"? Because that is what it is looking for and saying isn't there. I see you have the class but what namespace is it in?

Comment: Sure (located in the shared project). Else the project wouldn't compile.

Comment: Edited to reflect what I meant to say... sorry.

Comment: the myBinder and myAbstractService are both in com.www.shared which is importet by my MainActivity (App1, namespace com.www.app1) and myService (App2, namespace com.www.app2)