# ClassCastException in ServiceConnection.onServiceConnected(). Bound Services

Tags: android, binding, service, bind, serviceconnection

i try to bind a service to an activity. But i got the ClassCastException here:

```
pos.main.client.ClientBackground_Service.ClientBackground_Binder binder = (ClientBackground_Binder) service;
```

I don't really understand why i get this exception. The service is running as process. The activity want to fetch and use it.

Here are both classes:

```
public class ClientMain_Activity extends Activity
{
private boolean m_IsBound = false;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (isMyServiceRunning())
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ClientBackground_Service.class);
        bindService(intent, m_ServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

    }
}

private ServiceConnection m_ServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection()
{
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service)
    {

        pos.main.client.ClientBackground_Service.ClientBackground_Binder binder = (ClientBackground_Binder) service;
        // m_Service = binder.getService();
        m_IsBound = true;
    }
};
}
```

Service Class:

```
public class ClientBackground_Service extends Service implements
    I_ClientBackground_Service
{

private final IBinder m_clientbackground_binding = new ClientBackground_Binder();


public class ClientBackground_Binder extends Binder
{

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
{
    return m_clientbackground_binding;
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId)
{
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
    Log.i(this.getClass().getName(), " ClientBackground_Service started");
}
}
```

Comment: Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526938/classcastexception-when-binding-to-local-service-from-another-activity,  https://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/aidl.html

Comment: Service as a own process is a bad idea :)